# jQuery, getJSON and Windows 7 Gadgets

Tags: jquery, windows, widget, getjson, windows-desktop-gadgets

I've been coding a little application in jQuery / JavaScript that works fine in the browser (tested latest FF, Chrome and IE 9) but somehow the code just isn't working as a Windows Gadget. I was doing some research and I think it has to do with getJSON-calls to an external API in my script.

How can I get getJSON to work in my Windows Gadget?

Also, how can I debug widgets written in JavaScript/HTML? There seems to be no console or anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML and javascript-debugging is possible via "Firebug" a firefox-addon.. 
Try to debug your application, otherwise compare your getJSON-call with other getJSON-examples (e.g. http://www.jquery4u.com/json/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple/)

Comment: Another way to debug in IE is the browser addon Companion.JS